# which is the more effeicent way to create a simple callback in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calls array.forEach with a callback, would it be better to create the callback outside of the function like this

```
foo=(function(){    

  var f=function(v){
    //long function
  };

  return function (){
    array.forEach(f);
  };
}());
```

or just put it inline like this

```
function foo(){    
  array.forEach(function(v){
    //long function
  });
}
```

Since `//long function` is only created once or is it cached or something in example two?

**Edit:**

when I try
`a=function() {return function(){};}` `a()!==a()`
But when I do

```
a=(function() {
    var a=function(){};
    return function(){
        return a;
    };
}());
```

`a()===a()`

So does that mean less objects are created using number two?

Comment: `f` is only created once.

Comment: I think if you don't need to use that function somewhere else, you can have that `inline`. But sometimes I extract that in variable because it spoils indentation.

Comment: I know f is only created once but is the callback in example 2 created more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you're always returning references to the same function.  By the time your code runs, the JavaScript interpreter has already parsed the whole file and created all the functions in memory.  It's not creating a whole new copy of the function's code every time you return it.

---

The above is actually a little too simplistic, because JavaScript supports [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), which let you get different effects from returning the "same" function.  Consider the following code:

```
function makeGreeter(salutation) {
    return function(addressee) {
        return salutation + ", " + addressee + "!";
    }
}

var sayHelloTo = makeGreeter("Hello");
var sayGoodbyeTo = makeGreeter("Goodbye");

var helloWorld = sayHelloTo("World");  // "Hello, World!"
var helloUniverse = sayHelloTo("Universe");  // "Hello, Universe!"
var goodbyeWorld = sayGoodbyeTo("World");  // "Goodbye, World!"
var goodbyeUniverse = sayGoodbyeTo("Universe");  // "Goodbye, Universe!"
```

Clearly the `makeGreeter` function can't really return exactly the same thing every time, because `makeGreeter("Hello")` and `makeGreeter("Goodbye")` must produce different functions.  So you'll get two different function objects from those calls, but they're not complete copies of the function's code.  Instead they'll share the same code, but hold different values for the `salutation` parameter used by that code.

Comment: Aaah ok, I get that part now:)